# What are servlet container in Websphere Aplication Server Network Deployment v7 (not community edition)?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere

I saw the Tomcat v6.0.2 in a list of third-party components in notices.txt that came with the installation package. Does this mean that Tomcat used as a servlet/jsp container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a very good assumption to me.

A better clue would be to find Tomcat/Catalina JARs in an app server /lib directory.

I don't use WebSphere, so I can't confirm it for you myself.  Perhaps Google can.

The more I look on the web, the more it appears that WebSphere is *not* using Tomcat.  If you don't find JARs or scripts for Tomcat/Catalina, it's safe to say that IBM has their own.

Comment: I found only apache commons library. Tomkat was most likely on the list by accident. Thank you.

Comment: Just fyi: WebSphere' servlet engine was based on Tomcat till version 5.1 or so, then they wrote their own servlet container.